# Voice commands, bluetooth, double press home

Tags: bluetooth, voice-command

Is there a way to improve the voice recognition command when you press the bluetooth button or double press home? It's terrible. I've already 'trained' it or 'adapted' it. This isn't the same as Google voice search. The settings > about says

Nuance, VSuite 3.2, Version 3.2.55, Build 4.5.102

I tried going to manage app to see if I could share and look it up in the market for an update, but no luck. The phone is Droid2WE.

Answer (score 1):

Although we may not be referring to the same program, I had issues with Android's built in *Voice Dialer* app. There are a few replacement voice dialer apps on Google Play, including [Choice Dialer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.resounding.choicedialer.free).  In many of these alternative voice dialers, there are options for controlling the confidence threshold before taking an action.  In the case of Choice Dialer, if a command cannot be understood with a configurable level of confidence, it asks you to confirm with a simple *yes* or *no*.  I found that this alone made it a lot better than the built-in voice dialer.

So, to answer your question, consider getting a replacement voice dialer.

Comment: Shoot, it says:  
This app is incompatible with your Verizon Motorola DROID2 GLOBAL.

Comment: Tough break.  This is the only alternative voice dialer I have used and can vouch for.  There are a few others in Google Play, though.  Hope you find one that's better than the built in one.